# How to run jsprit using maven

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface, jsprit

Im new to using maven, and am trying to run the "SimpleExample.java" listed on the jsprit library github you can find the setup instructions [here](https://github.com/jsprit/jsprit/wiki/Simple-Example) and the source code [here](https://github.com/jsprit/jsprit/blob/v1.6/jsprit-examples/src/main/java/jsprit/examples/SimpleExample.java).

I setup the directories as per some maven tutorials I found, and the contents of POM are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-maven</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <dependencies> <!-- add this, if you don't have any dependency definitions yet -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>jsprit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsprit-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>jsprit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsprit-analysis</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>jsprit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsprit-instances</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies> <!-- add this, if you don't have any dependency definitions yet -->

    <repositories> <!-- add this, if you don't have any repository definitions yet -->
      <repository>
        <id>jsprit-releases</id>
        <url>https://github.com/jsprit/mvn-rep/raw/master/releases</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories> <!-- add this, if you don't have any repository definitions yet -->

    <build>
    </build>
</project>
```

After running mvn compile -> mvn install -> mvn package. I go to the target directory and run the following command in my terminal:

```
java -cp gs-maven-0.1.0.jar test.SimpleExample
```

Note: my projects name is test. After running this command, I get the error below. Please advise if you know how to solve this issue. Thanks.

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jsprit/core/problem/vehicle/VehicleType
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jsprit.core.problem.vehicle.VehicleType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: you need to pack your dependencies as well with the packaged jar, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me!